# Convert System.Int32 to System.UIntPtr

Tags: c#, powershell, pinvoke

I'm using the P/Invoke functionality in PowerShell to call the Win32 `VirtualProtectEx` function.

For the third parameter it requires an unsigned int pointer as an argument , according to the function signature

> `static extern bool VirtualProtectEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress,
>      UIntPtr dwSize, uint flNewProtect, out uint lpflOldProtect);`.

What I have though is a variable called `$shellcode` and want to write that to some memory address, so I need to reserve `$shellcode.Length` bytes. I can't figure out who to cast to the pointer though. I did already try

`[System.UIntPtr]$shellcode.Length`

```
# Set memory for shellcode to Execute and Read
$oldProtect = 0
$procHandle.GetType().fullname
$basePtr.GetType().fullname
$shellcode.Length.GetType().fullname
$PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE.GetType().fullname
$oldProtect.GetType().fullname
$result = $Kernel32::VirtualProtectEx($procHandle, $basePtr, $shellcode.Length, $PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, [ref] $oldProtect);
```

But it returns

```
System.IntPtr
System.IntPtr
System.Int32
System.Int32
System.Int32
Cannot convert argument "dwSize", with value: "168", for "VirtualProtectEx" to type
"System.UIntPtr": "Cannot convert the "168" value of type "System.Int32" to type
"System.UIntPtr"."
At C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\malware.ps1:59 char:1
+ $result = $Kernel32::VirtualProtectEx($procHandle, $basePtr, $shellco ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Comment: This worked! If you want to add this as an answer I'll mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uintptr.-ctor#System_UIntPtr__ctor_System_UInt32_): `[UIntPtr]::new($shellcode.Length)`.